# Tool for debugging Jpeg 2000 images

Tags: jpeg, jpeg2000

I normally use JPEGsoop to peek into jpeg images. Is there a tool kit library or program that I can use to peek into structure of Jpeg 2000 images ?

I saw 

[John Bokma Java
freelance Perl programmer
Obtaining image metadata](http://johnbokma.com/java/obtaining-image-metadata.html)

I suppose I will build that program anyway .

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: The URL is http://johnbokma.com/java/obtaining-image-metadata.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think imagemagick esp. its tool "identify" might help you.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: Thanks a lot Ingo. I downloaded imagemagic